# Skip text in output with grep in perl mode

Tags: grep, regular-expression, perl

I have text like this:

```
blah, blah <foo:ImportantText> blah blah time=1.234 blah blah
blah, blah <foo:AlsoImportant> blah blah blah time=9.9 blah blah
blah, blah <foo:ImportantText> blah blah time=0.987 blah blah
```

I want to get:

```
<foo:ImportantText>=1.234
<foo:AlsoImportant>=9.9
<foo:ImportantText>=0.987
```

I use this line:

```
grep -Po '(<foo:.+>).+time=(\d+.\d+)' logfile.txt
```

- Note I don't need to worry about false positives as `<foo:` and `time=` do not appear elsewhere in the text. Also `blah blah` is random text, not a literal.

This gives me:

```
<foo:ImportantText> blah blah time=1.234
<foo:AlsoImportant> blah blah blah time=9.9
<foo:ImportantText> blah blah time=0.987
```

How do I drop the intermediate text? I thought `'(<foo:.+>)(?=.+time)=(\d+.\d+)'` might work, but it doesn't.

**Update**:

```
grep -Po '(<foo:.+>).+time=(\d+.\d+)' logfile.txt
                | awk -F ' ' '{print $1substr($NF,4)}'
```

This works, but is there a `grep`-only solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/.*(<foo:.+>).+time=([0-9.]+).*/\1=\2/' logfile.txt 
<foo:ImportantText>=1.234
<foo:AlsoImportant>=9.9
<foo:ImportantText>=0.987
```

Comment: I tend to only use `grep` and `awk` for everything, but that is a much easier solution.

Comment: I can't do one character edits here, but that's `sed` not `ed`.